# SQL: Can it be solved better way?

Tags: mysql, sql

Asking as I'm sure it can :)

So,

Have a simple log table:

```
CREATE TABLE `log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,  << AUTOINC
  `action` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `source` varchar(20) ,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  `message` varchar(100) 
) ;
```

Log is filled with sensor data but what is important the sensors read sequence is  being called every 1 minute. So every minute 2 new rows (2 sensors) are supposed to be added (not always true - like on sensor failure).

Here live log table data taken few minutes ago:

```
id   action source                  time                  message
9468    3   TEMP_28-021501c7b0ff    2015-06-04 23:28:03     24437
9467    3   TEMP_10-000802b59f3f    2015-06-04 23:28:02     24375
9466    3   TEMP_28-021501c7b0ff    2015-06-04 23:27:03     24437
9465    3   TEMP_10-000802b59f3f    2015-06-04 23:27:02     24375
9464    3   TEMP_28-021501c7b0ff    2015-06-04 23:26:03     24437
9463    3   TEMP_10-000802b59f3f    2015-06-04 23:26:02     24375
9462    3   TEMP_28-021501c7b0ff    2015-06-04 23:25:04     24437
9461    3   TEMP_10-000802b59f3f    2015-06-04 23:25:02     24312
9460    3   TEMP_28-021501c7b0ff    2015-06-04 23:24:03     24437
9459    3   TEMP_10-000802b59f3f    2015-06-04 23:24:02     24375
```

As you can see sensors are being read every minute and delivers almost the same values in 'message' column.

The point is that I have to change the table layout so it will have both 'messages' in a row timestamped with first sensor read time.

So result should looks like:

```
2015-06-04 23:28:03     24437 24375
2015-06-04 23:27:03     24437 24375
2015-06-04 23:26:03     24437 24375
etc
```

It seems I have found the solution but it looks terrible:

```
SELECT l1.time as l1time,l1.message as l1mess , l2.message as l2mess, 
FROM log l1,log l2 
WHERE l1.source LIKE 'TEMP_10%' AND l2.source LIKE 'TEMP_28%' 
AND l2.id-l1.id=1 AND l1.action=3 AND l2.action=3 
AND ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,l2.time,l1.time))<10;
```

There is better solution, for sure ...

Comment: You could clean it up a little by moving the logic into 2 views. Perhaps CHARINDEX instead of like too.

Comment: You've not provided enough information to give a full answer. Are the sensors polled in the same order each time? What level of jitter do you need to accommodate? Do you have the ability to modify the code controlling the polling? And, most importantly, what are your criteria for "better"?

Comment: Yes they are polled in the same order but their count and names can change (System polls what is connected to the bus). Yes I can change the inserting code (but have in mind log covers data from other sources not shown here so one more column just for that issue is two much). Better  means better SQL syntax and faster result :)

Comment: What do you mean by BETTER ? more readable code, faster responce, or something else ?

Comment: As wrote above it means cleaner SQL syntax and lower CPU load ...

Comment: Does the solution have to be SQL, or could you do this outside of the database using some scripting language (like PHP)?

Comment: I would write that like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03b64/6) and I'm not quite sure  is that timediff necessary and why...

Comment: Can you guarantee they are within a certain number of seconds from each other?

Comment: Can guaratee bus is being read every 1min, and every sensor read lasts for about 1-2 sec.   @AleksandarMiladinovic:It seems to me it's important as we have to be sure we are getting sensor data from one bus poll.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine, its cleaner syntax and i think more efficient:

```
select q0.`time`, q0.`message`, q1.`message` from
( select `id`, `time`, `message` from `log` where `source` = 'TEMP_10-000802b59f3f'
) as q0
,
( select `id`, `time`, `message` from `log` where `source` = 'TEMP_28-021501c7b0ff'
  ) as q1
where 
ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,q0.`time`,q1.`time`))<10
and abs(q0.`id`-q1.`id`)=1;
```

- Notice that `like` operator is not the good choice if we can use `=`
- If the `action=3` filter is always true, do not use it, else, put then in the inner queries q0 and q1

Here is a live [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c666c/11)

Comment: Looks better :) Just add final  'AND q1.id-q0.id=1'; to eliminate duplicates and be sure pairs are take right. .

Comment: Using subqueries in MySQL pretty much precludes any possibility of optimizing the query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff does it is the case for this question ?

Comment: @54l3d . . . Yes, the conditions can go in the `WHERE` or `ON` clauses without the subqueries.

Comment: @54l3d Made more tests and it seems the result set is somehow wrong. The result rows numer seems to be about 25% of the source while it should be 50% +-1 row. Here you have bigger dataset (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c666c/1)

Answer (score 0):

Your query better formatted:

```
SELECT l1.time as l1time,l1.message as l1mess, l2.message as l2mess, 
FROM log l1 JOIN
     log l2 
     ON l1.source LIKE 'TEMP_10%' AND l2.source LIKE 'TEMP_28%' AND
        l2.id - l1.id = 1 AND l1.action = 3 AND l2.action = 3 ABD
        ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,l2.time, l1.time)) < 10;
```

This may be the best way to write the query . . . almost.  To best use indexes (`log(action, id)`, for instance), this `on` clause is better:

```
     ON l1.source LIKE 'TEMP_10%' AND l2.source LIKE 'TEMP_28%' AND
        l2.id = l1.id + 1 AND l1.action = 3 AND l2.action = 3 ABD
        ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, l2.time, l1.time)) < 10;
```

I'm not 100% sure that this actually does what you really need.  But you do claim that this query works for you.

Comment: Tested and it seems to work (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c666c/1)  @SteveCav said CHARINDEX would be an improvemnt as well ..

Comment: @PaulPaku . . . That is not true.  SQL Server will optimize `LIKE 'TEMP_10%` if an index is available.  `CHARINDEX()` cannot be optimized.